# Automatically increase cell distance for all longtable/tabu environments

Tags: longtable, line-spacing

I have a document with many longtable and tabu environments. Is there any way to increase the distance between the cells without having to change them manually in each longtable? I know about `\doublespacing`, but this increases the line spacing. 
If I have an environment like this:

```
\documentclass[
, twoside
, 12pt
, a4paper
, english
, numbers=noenddot
, bibliography=totoc
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| p{4,5cm} | p{11,5cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Variablenbezeichnung} & \textbf{Kurzbeschreibung}\\
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    V1&\\
    id&BASE-ID\\
    % I want to increase the distance here!
    example & definition\\


    \hline
    \caption{My Variables}
  \end{longtable}
 \begin{center}
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{14.5em} | m{25em} | }
        \hline
        \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Description} \\ \hline
        vpid & subjects ID\\
        CT\_ACC & Accuracy\\
        CT\_CRT & Correct response time\\
        CT\_NCRT & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Control task aggregated variables}
    \label{table:controlVariables}
\end{table}
\end{center}
  \end{document}
```

how would I increase the distance between the cells? I am thinking about a single command that changes all of them in every table. I hope I didn't forget any of the packages that are relevant for this topic (I think I have to many to include them all)

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

seems to delete my tabular inside table environment... But I can't recreate this, not even if I use all my meta information and the concerned table in another document.

Comment: As you don't show a MWE: Using the package `array` you could use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`.

Comment: What for do you need `tabu`?

Comment: The problem with `\arraystretch` is the cell contents is no more vertically centred in the cell. Do you want this to happen for all table-like environments or only for longtable?

Comment: It is possible that I have some `tabu` tables in my document, but this shouldn't be the problem, or am I wrong? I want this to happen for all table-like environments.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code I did:

- use the package `array` and its `\arraystretch` to increase the cell distance,
- use the package `booktabs` to make the table look more professional (see its documentation) by removing vertical lines and
- show you that you can (as always) introduce a distance to `\\`.

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{4.5cm}p{11.5cm}@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Variablenbezeichnung} & \textbf{Kurzbeschreibung}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    V1&\\
    id&BASE-ID\\
    example & definition\\[2em]
    test & test\\
    \bottomrule
    \caption{My Variables}
  \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I wanted it to do! I didn't think it would be this easy. I know that I can introduce a distance to `\\`, but I didn't do it when I created the tables and now I have over 50 of them.

Comment: However, this command somehow seems to interfere with my tabulars inside the table environmen... The variables aren't shown anymore... I defined it like this: \begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{14.5em} | m{25em} | }

Comment: @LizzAlice Please then update your question. Especially with a compilable document (add documentclass, necessary packages and column definitions in addition to the table).

Comment: I did, but unfortunately, I wasn't able to reproduce the error... Even if I create a document with all of my meta information and the two tables in question, the longtable that works and the tabular that doesn't, both are shown like they should. But in the original full document, the error still exists. Do you maybe have any suggestions on how to isolate the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can have this spacing with package `makecell`: the command `\setcellgapes{some length}`  defines a vertical padding to add at the top and bottom of cells in a table, and the command `\makegapedcells` makes this padding effective for all tabular-like environments that follow.

In the following code I added `4pt` at the top and bottom of all cells. Also, I took the liberty to place the longtable caption on top of the table, in accordance to the typographic tradition (for long tables, the reader usually does not want to have to skim through pages to know what the table is about):

```
\documentclass[
, twoside
, 12pt
, a4paper
, english
, numbers=noenddot
, bibliography=totoc
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells

\begin{longtable}{| p{4,5cm} | p{10.3cm} |}
    \caption{My Variables} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Variablenbezeichnung} & \textbf{Kurzbeschreibung}\\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
    \textbf{Variablenbezeichnung} & \textbf{Kurzbeschreibung}\\
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    V1&\\
    id&BASE-ID\\
    % I want to increase the distance here!
    example & definition\\
    \hline
  \end{longtable}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{14em}|p{22em} | }
        \hline
        \textbf{Variables} & \textbf{Description} \\ \hline
        vpid & subjects ID\\
        CT\_ACC & Accuracy\\
        CT\_CRT & Correct response time\\
        CT\_NCRT & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Control task aggregated variables}
    \label{table:controlVariables}
\end{table}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work with tabu, does it? If I execute this, I only get `! Missing $ inserted.`...